# How to tween an object to target without any tween libraries and without easing?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I want to tween an object to targetX and targetY without any tween libraries and without easing.

I have always used greensock for all my tweens and for this case greensock's DynamicPropsPlugin would be perfect, but its only for club members......

This time I need to tween an object to target which will be changing dynamically.

I know how to tween objects with easing, but this time I need to tween an object without it, so after reaching its first target it would continue smoothly to next target.

This is code that works, but the problem is the easing:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author me
     */
    [SWF(width="1200", height="600", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#ffffff")]
    public class Test extends Sprite 
    {

        // first target coordinates
        private var targetX:Number=600;
        private var targetY:Number = 450;

        // second target coordinates
        private var targetX2:Number=900;
        private var targetY2:Number = 300;

        // check if first target is reached
        private var _pointReached:Boolean

        // object to tween
        private var _ball:Sprite;

        public function Test() 
        {
            init()
        }

        private function init():void 
        {
            // simple ball 
            _ball = new Sprite();
            _ball.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            _ball.graphics.drawCircle( -50, -50, 50);
            _ball.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(_ball);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);
        }

        private function onLoop(e:Event):void 
        {
            var vx:Number; 
            var vy:Number; 

            if (_pointReached) { // next target
                // easing
                vx = (targetX2 - _ball.x) * .3;
                vy = (targetY2 - _ball.y) * .3;
            }else {
                // easing
                vx = (targetX - _ball.x) * .3;
                vy = (targetY - _ball.y) * .3;
            }

            // check distance
            var dx:Number = targetX - _ball.x;
            var dy:Number = targetY - _ball.y;
            var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if (dist <= 0.6) {
                // first target point reached
                _pointReached = true;
            }

            // tween an object
            _ball.x += vx;
            _ball.y += vy;

        }

    }

}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Just become clubmember. TweenLite is a great opensouce library, you probebly used it in many projects, so just give it back, its not that expensive. The club feature are very nice btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer class and inside timer function move the object towards the target. Do it till the object reaches the target position.

Comment: Timer class is not relevant in this case and I'm moving the object towards its target :). Please read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (UNTESTED):

```
private function onLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        var xDistance:Number; 
        var yDistance:Number; 

        if (_pointReached) { // next target
            xDistance = _ball.x - targetX2;
            yDistance = _ball.y - targetY2;

        }else {
            xDistance = _ball.x - targetX;
            yDistance =  _ball.y - targetY;

        }

        var rotation:Number = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance);

        var speed:int = 2;

        // tween an object
        _ball.x -= speed * Math.cos(rotation);
        _ball.y -= speed * Math.cos(rotation);

        if (dist <= 0.6) {
            // first target point reached
            _pointReached = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, on the lines that look similar to this:

vx = (targetX - _ball.x) * .3;

remove the * .3 part.  That is your friction or easing.  Your code should then work without easing.